# How safe is your source code from your hosts?

Tags: php, security, hosting

Curious on how safe can your PHP source code be from the servers you put them on. Would a hosting company steal or do anything with your code that you would not want them to do?

Comment: Read those private policy. If someone stolen your code and you can prove it, you can sue them.

Comment: Second what nemoden said. I read this question first as a "could or would this happen," but if you're really asking "did this just happen to me," that's an entirely different question. It's certainly possible, but very uncommon with reputable hosting providers.

Comment: I think question probably belongs on programmers.se, but voting to move it, will cause it to closed as off topic :/

Answer (score 3):

Could? Yes. Would? Not unless they're owned by the Russian Mafia. Use a reputable hosting provider.

Comment: Russian Mafia? :) Why everybody in the world thinks all we do is we drink vodka and we are badasses ? :)) Sorry for off-topic.

Comment: @Nemoden: because we all drink vodka and act as a badasses ;-P

Comment: Ah.... Who am I fooling? You are right. Let's go drink vodka :)

Answer (score 1):

It depends on your hosting company's terms of service, and also the kind of service for which you are paying.

If you're in a shared hosting environment, chances are the hosting company will reserve the right to look at your code, in case it's causing performance issues for other customers.

If you're paying for a dedicated server, your host probably doesn't care what you do on there (unless you get them RBL'ed) and wouldn't even bother taking the time to look at your code.